# Spring Security 3.1: How To Get Security To Kick In At An Alternative Entry Point

Tags: java, authentication, spring-security

I'm new to Spring.   I've recently learned to use Spring 3.1 to implement LDAP authentication. I was told to customize the authentication such that if a user from an IP address in the database comes to the site that s/he will be automatically logged in( not my idea, I was ordered to do it ).  If not, that person will be sent to a login screen to do LDAP authentication

I made a skeleton of a custom PreAuthenticationFilter to check such users out, determine if they are from one of the annointed IP addresses and then send them to the rest of the authentication process.

I'm brand spanking new to Spring.  So I cobbled this together from examples and reading over the reference many times.

When I try running it I get an error message that seems to me I am not setting up my tags properly or that I am leaving a big piece out ( do I need a second, custom, AuthenticationEntry point?)

Any tips in getting past this error would be appreciated:

**the excerpt from my log**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
 Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains': 
 Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0' 
 while setting bean property 'sourceList' with key [0]; 
 nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
 Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0': 
 Cannot resolve reference to bean 'customFilter' 
 while setting constructor argument with key [2]; 
 nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
 Error creating bean with name 'customFilter' 
 defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/acme-security.xml]: 
 Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
 An AuthenticationManager must be set
```

**My customized PreAuthenticatedFilter class for logging in by IP Address:**

```
package com.acme.controller.security;


import java.io.*;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;


import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationDetailsSource;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AuthenticationFailureHandler; 
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetailsSource;


import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class CustomIPAddressAuthenticationFilter extends AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter {

  private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(CustomIPAddressAuthenticationFilter.class);

  private AuthenticationDetailsSource ads             = new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource();
  private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
  private AuthenticationFailureHandler failureHandler = new SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler();

  public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

    if (authentication == null) {       

        boolean isAuthenticatedByIP  = false;

        // Get the IP address of the user tyring to use the site
        String userIPAddress = request.getRemoteAddr();
        logger.debug("userIPAddress == " + userIPAddress);

        // Compare the user's IP Address with the IP address in the database
        // stored in the USERS_AUTHENTICATED_BY_IP table & joined to the
        // USERS tabe to make sure the IP Address has a current user
        //isAuthenticatedByIP =  someDataObject.hasIPAddress(userIPAddress);
        isAuthenticatedByIP = true;

        if(isAuthenticatedByIP){
            PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken token = new PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken("John.Principal","Password");
            token.setDetails(ads.buildDetails(request));

            try{
                logger.debug("Going to set Authentication");
                authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(token);
                // Setup the security context, aka authenticate
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
                logger.debug("Authenticated");
            }
            catch(AuthenticationException e){
                logger.debug("Authentication information was rejected by the authentication manager \n",e);
                failureHandler.onAuthenticationFailure((HttpServletRequest)request, (HttpServletResponse)response, e);
            }



        }// end if(isAuthenticatedByIP)     

    }// end if(authenication == null)

    chain.doFilter(request, response);
  }// end function doFilter();

  public void setAuthenticationManager(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
    this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
  }

  public void setFailureHandler(AuthenticationFailureHandler failureHandler) {
    this.failureHandler = failureHandler;
  }


  protected String getPreAuthenticatedPrincipal(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request){

      return "Joe.IP.User";
  }

  protected String getPreAuthenticatedCredentials(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request){
      return "Password2";
  }




}
```

**My *-security.xml:**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:s="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

    <s:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">

        <s:intercept-url pattern="/login*"    access="hasRole('ROLE_ANONYMOUS')"/>
        <s:intercept-url pattern="/search*"   access="hasRole('ROLE_ANONYMOUS')"/>
        <s:intercept-url pattern="/css/**"    access="hasRole('ROLE_ANONYMOUS')"/>
        <s:intercept-url pattern="/js/**"     access="hasRole('ROLE_ANONYMOUS')"/>
        <s:intercept-url pattern="/images/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ANONYMOUS')"/>
        <s:intercept-url pattern="/jsp/test*" access="hasRole('ROLE_ANONYMOUS')"/>
        <s:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />

        <s:custom-filter position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" ref="customFilter" />

        <s:form-login login-page="/login"
          authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed" />
        <s:logout logout-success-url="/logout" />
    </s:http>


    <bean id="customFilter" class="com.acme.controller.security.CustomIPAddressAuthenticationFilter">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
    </bean>

    <s:ldap-server url = "ldap://ldap-itc.smen.acme.com:636/o=acme.com"/>

    <s:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <s:ldap-authentication-provider user-dn-pattern="uid={0},ou=People"/>
    </s:authentication-manager>


</beans>
```

**My web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app  id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0"
   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">


  <display-name>Acme</display-name>

  <!--welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/login</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list-->

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>acme</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>acme</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>


  <!-- Help Find The Spring Config Files -->
  <listener>
    <listener-class>
                  org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
  </listener>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/nsd-servlet.xml,
            /WEB-INF/nsd-security.xml
    </param-value>
  </context-param>


  <!-- Spring Security -->
  <filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>


  <!-- Integrate A Legacy Screen Done With A Servlet -->
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>HelloWorldServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
            com.legacy.HelloWorldServlet
    </servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>HelloWorldServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/helloworldservlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe some part of your security configuration is inconsistent in the way you use `s:http` in several places in the configuration. I suggest trying the following configuration:

```
<s:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">

    <s:intercept-url pattern="/login*" access="isAnonymous()" />
    <s:intercept-url pattern="/search*" access="isAnonymous()" />
    <s:intercept-url pattern="/css/**" access="isAnonymous()" />
    <s:intercept-url pattern="/js/**" access="isAnonymous()" />
    <s:intercept-url pattern="/images/**" access="isAnonymous()" />
    <s:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />

    <s:form-login login-page="/login"
      authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed" />
    <s:logout logout-success-url="/logout" />

</s:http>
```

You need to activate the authentication process regardless of hitting `/login`; so I suggest using an implementation of a pre-authenticated *filter* [`AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/preauth.html). Your filter will do the authentication using IP address and populate the `Authentication` object thus not redirecting to the login page anymore. The filter should be configured in the position `PRE_AUTH_FILTER`. You can find a similar use case implementation for GAE here at [Spring Source blog](http://blog.springsource.com/2010/08/02/spring-security-in-google-app-engine/).

Comment: I just tried that and I got an error message.  I posted the new file and the error message at the bottom of my original post under "Update"

Comment: Okay, I got your suggestion working, no error message, but no difference in outcome.

Comment: Updated the answer, hope it helps.

Comment: Okay, I took your suggestion.  I updated my original post with the new code.  I'm hitting a new error I don't understand.  Thanks in advance for any clues.

Comment: The bean definition tag `bean id="customIPAddressAuthenticationFilter"` should be moved outside `s:http`.

Comment: Thanks!  I tried that and got different errors.  I hacked my way through 2 more sets of similar errors.  I'm left scratching my head with the 3rd.  I just don't understand enough about Spring yet.  I updated all of my files above, including the new error message I am stuck on.  Any tips in getting past that I would be grateful for.  Thanks in advance either way.

Comment: Note that this configuration won't work since `ROLE_ANONYMOUS` isn't an EL expression. You need to use `isAnonymous()` or `permitAll` instead.

Comment: @Steve The exception is complaining about that your custom filter needs an instance of `AuthenticationManager` (refer to [source](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/xref/org/springframework/security/ui/preauth/AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.html#55)). Surprisingly, your configuration looks fine and is configuring the authentication manager. A wild guess could that you test this configuration in a separate simple project to make sure it works.

Comment: nobeh, my code is already in a simple separate project.  I've been developing it on my own time, outside of work with the hope of cobbling it into a project at work before I have to put more conventional authentication code in.   Thanks for the note about the config looking fine.  I noticed that the other examples don't have a method to set the AM, mine does. I'm going to try removing that first, then reading the docs you linked to try to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

In your implementation you need to eliminate the attribute `authenticationManager`, It is managed by the parent class.